# Using cedet semantic wisent-ruby

Tags: ruby, emacs, folding, cedet, emacs-semantic

I'm just getting started setting up cedet following various guides including Alex Ott's.

Here is what I have so far in my init file.

```
(require 'cedet)
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)

;; imenu breaks if I don't enable this
(global-semantic-highlight-func-mode 1)

(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode)
```

I quite like the code folding, because semantic know more about code than packages like hideshow, etc.

I would like to have the same folding for ruby.  I know there is other stuff cedet does, but I'm just dipping my toes in for now.

So I see in the contrib/ folder there is wisent-ruby.el.  It sure looks like semantic knows how to parse Ruby.  The INSTALL says that it's supposed to be installed "automatically".  I open up a Ruby file and code folding magic triangles aren't there.  What now?

Comment: As a note to those who came here through Google.  I've since stopped using Cedet for Ruby, the parser doesn't work well enough and is no longer being developed.

Comment: What are you using instead? RSense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see in `contrib-loaddefs.el`, correct hooks & autoloads are generated only for php & C# modes.  You can explicitly load `wisent-ruby` and setup corresponding hook, as in following example:

```
(require 'wisent-ruby)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook #'wisent-ruby-default-setup)
```

but I hadn't checked, does folding works for Ruby or not (because I also don't know status of Ruby parser).  You can write to cedet mailing list with more questions about `wisent-ruby`...

Comment: Code folding works great.  There are a couple of issues with wisent-ruby.el, which I'm trying to sort out on the cedet-devel mailing list.

Comment: Yes, mailing list is best place to discuss such problems ;-)